# Mysql_fetch_object() SQL Query (HOW TO: If no results found, display "message" )?

Tags: php, sql

I've spent hours trying to make this work. No solutions from the search have helped me, so I'm finally asking.

What I'm trying to do is: **Display a message if no results are found**.

This is what I have, and it is currently not working to my dismay.

```sql
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cover WHERE MATCH(keyword,description,categories) AGAINST('$search_key' in boolean mode) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $from , $perPage");

    $i=1;
    while($result = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {

    $keyword = $result->keyword;
    $img = $result->img;
    $description = $result->description;

    if($img != null) { DO THIS;
    if($i==2) { require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/page.php'); }
    $i++; }
    }
    if($img == null) { print "<center>No Results Found</center>"; }
```

I don't know how to use **mysql_num_rows** with this (which is what I've seen is the most popular solution around the site), it returns an error and I'm thinking it doesn't work well with `mysql_fetch_object($sql)` **?**  And I don't think this: `$img = $result->img;` would work with mysql_num_rows either.

I'm just trying to find a way to do this without having to modify anything inside the brackets, just the ones outside.

---

**When I say "NOT WORKING"**, I mean it doesn't show the message that is supposed to show if results are not found. I've tested `if($img != null) { print "<center>No Results Found</center>"; }` and it works fine, it shows the message. But it doesn't seem to work the other way, and I'm now just confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cover WHERE MATCH(keyword,description,categories) AGAINST('$search_key' in boolean mode) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $from , $perPage");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{
    $i=1;
    while($result = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) 
    {
        $keyword = $result->keyword;
        $img = $result->img;
        $description = $result->description;

        if($img != null) 
        { 
            DO THIS;
            if($i==2) 
            { 
                require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/page.php'); 
            }
            $i++; 
        }
    }
}
else
{ 
    print "<center>No Results Found</center>"; 
}
```

I see no reason why you would want to store the values from `$result` into separate variables when you can simply use the `$result->keyword` directly.

Comment: Thanks Gavin, this was **exactly what I was looking for**! I found a different way to get what I wanted through @Kasyx method, but this was what my question was about and you have answered it. About the using different variables when I could just use `$result->keyword`, well I purchased the script this way and the bulk within the brackets I just don't want to go through or modify anymore. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have doubts with mysql_num_rows look at your index:

```
$i = 1;
```

If there are no results then value after loop will be still 1, so you need to check AFTER while loop:

```
if($i == 1) { print "<center>No Results Found</center>"; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Kasyx, this one worked! I tried doing it this way before too but couldn't figure out the method, I was trying `if($1==0)`. Thanks for this, finally got this thing off my head. **:o)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
  if(mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0);
    {
    echo 'There is no result';
    }
    else
     {
       your code
    }
```

Here is the implementation of this in your code

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cover WHERE MATCH(keyword,description,categories) AGAINST('$search_key' in boolean mode) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $from , $perPage");

    $i=1;
    $result = mysql_fetch_object($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 )
    {
    while($result) {

    $keyword = $result->keyword;
    $img = $result->img;
    $description = $result->description;

    if($img != null) { DO THIS;
    if($i==2) { require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/page.php'); }
    $i++; }
    }
    if($img == null) { print "<center>No Results Found</center>"; }
    }
   else
     {
         echo 'There is no result';
     }
```

Comment: it should be `0 === mysql_num_rows($sql)`

Comment: @Pramod, thank you, but then I don't think that would work with this: `$img = $result->img;`, and I use a lot of that, and the code is very bulky within those brackets so I don't want to touch anything in between anymore. I just want to find a way to make the outside of those brackets work.

Comment: Thank you, using your code I get a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF` on the 5th line of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that the while() loop only occurs IF a result are returned, so the NULL comparisons will never be raised  inside this.

I suggest you need to reorder the code like so:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cover WHERE MATCH(keyword,description,categories) AGAINST('$search_key' in boolean mode) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $from , $perPage");
$numResults = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($numResults === 0) { // mysql_query returned no results
    print "<center>No Results Found</center>";
} else { 
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/page.php');
    while($result = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) 
    {
        $keyword = $result->keyword;
        $img = $result->img;
        $description = $result->description;
    }
}
```