# Comparing SQL Statements if else style

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there a way that I can check if a value is present within another table and run different statements if it is do I factor **NOT EXISTS** into my sql statement?

Example:

If `prod_id`is not found in the `products_images` table then run `Code One` else run `Code Two`:

**Code 1:**

```
DELETE FROM $table WHERE $table.id ='$product_id
```

**Code 2:**

```
SELECT prod.id, img.product_id FROM `default_ps_products` prod INNER JOIN `default_ps_product_images` img ON prod.id = img.product_id where prod.id = 92
```

Comment: Here you can find the reference what you are looking for

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913047/mysql-fetch-object-sql-query-how-to-if-no-results-found-display-message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However, you need to execute two SQL queries in which, the first one is mandatory. You can use php to execute the first query and if it returns zero rows, you can execute the code 1, else code 2 using php's `if-else` statement.

```
$result = mysql->query("SELECT product_id FROM table WHERE product_id = $prod_id");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) !== 0)
    mysqli->query( CODE 1 )
else
    mysqli->query( CODE 2 )
```

If you care about efficiency, you can use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for executing MySQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

If this must be entirely contained in the Database, I'd look at implementing it as a stored procedure.

Something like this:

```
DELIMITER //  

CREATE PROCEDURE `myProc` (IN prodIdVar INT)  
    LANGUAGE SQL  
    DETERMINISTIC  
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE prodCount INT
    SELECT count(*) INTO prodCount FROM products_images WHERE product_id=prodIdVar;
    IF prodCount = 0 THEN
        DELETE QUERY GOES HERE;
    ELSE
        SELECT QUERY GOES HERE;
    END IF;
END//
```

Please bear in mind that this probably isn't perfect I haven't tested it. Just an illustration.